# How to set what IP address Exchange 2013 uses to send e-mail?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Our company is switching to doing e-mail filtering locally.

At the moment our Send Connector is set to **Route mail through smart hosts** but we will be switching this to **MX record associated with recipient domain**.

Our connection has multiple public IP addresses and I do not want e-mail sent using the default IP address. How can we set what IP address Exchange 2013 uses to send e-mail so that e-mail always comes from a certain IP address?

Comment: This is a firewall situation.

Comment: @ewwhite Thank you for the information. I was unaware that this couldn't be done in Exchange itself, as I'm primarily Linux based and nearly all server software provides a `bind-ip` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need your router model for a better answer.

Globally, You add an internal gateway IP on your router to use that specific IP. (like if 192.168.1.1 is your main gateway, you add 192.168.1.2 in example)

After you configure your Exchange to use that default gateway.

It's a good setup, as it will protect the IP to be blacklisted in RBL list if a user got infected.

After to be more secure, you configure some restriction on your router to allow only your Exchange on that port.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The firewall is a ZyWALL USG 200. Do you have any idea how I accomplish this using that? "It's a good setup, as it will protect the IP to be blacklisted in RBL list if a user got infected." Yes, that was my thinking of wanting to do it.

Comment: @user598200 I dont know that brand, but from that manual; http://www.manualslib.com/manual/363461/Zyxel-Communications-Zywall-Usg-20.html?page=146#manual It seem to be a mapping that you do with the source IP to be your Exchange server. So I think the zywall will use same lan ip, but will map a different wan ip depending on your rule

Comment: Thank you again, I've managed to set it up using that link!